# HTTPS hosted Deezer player not loading crossdomain.xml with an HTTPS connection

Tags: deezer

I have a test app hosted on an HTTPS server using the Deezer Javascript player. I'm using the https links for the player code and channel.html links.

Everything has been working fine for a few weeks until today when I'm now getting errors about http://cdn-proxy-4.deezer.com/crossdomain.xml being loaded over http instead of https.

My code hasn't changed since this problem started so I'm wondering if there is currently an issue with the Deezer API servers not using the correct protocol to request the crossdomain file?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the issue still exists. I'm getting the same warning/error. Did you find a solution?